# Где можно скачать blender game engine

Tags: разработка-игр, blender

На каком сайте можно найти и скачать blender game engine? Если можно то на официальном сайте если там есть.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не по теме.

Comment: https://upbge.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прямо на оф. сайте можно и [скачать](https://www.blender.org/download/) и доки полистать

Comment: На сайте же простой blender 2.82, а мне нужно blender game engine. Или это одно и тоже?

Comment: Сейчас это все в 1 инструменте, также как и в Unity

Comment: А можете дать несколько уроков по blender game engine? Если нет то какой нужно выбирать проект когда создаёшь новый файл?

Comment: @kiber в чем проблема зайти на [youtube и поискать](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=blender+game+engine+%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)?

Comment: Ну по поводу уроков, рекомендую Youtube, там много толковых уроков от а до я.

Answer (score 2):

Последняя версия Blender, в которой есть BGE - это версия 2.79. Её можно скачать с официального сайта в том его [разделе](https://download.blender.org/release/) где опубликованы все доступные релизы. BGE после этого [релиза Blender](https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/) был безвозвратно выпилен из дистрибутива Blender 2.8x.

Comment: Что, однако, не помешало его форкнуть в проекте upbge.org